# How make UDP socket receive packets from multiple senders and run the commands in each packet and print stdout/stderr back to the original sender?

Tags: c, sockets, udp

I run the following C program with the following command in one terminal.

```
./main 1337
```

Then I run the following command in another terminal.

```
nc -u localhost 1337 <<< 'ls -l --color=always'
```

But it does not allow UDP from multiple senders.

Could anybody show me how to make the server to handle UDP packets from multiple senders simultaneously and send the stdout/stderr back to the respective sender?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

void perrdie(const char *msg) {
    perror(msg);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int sockfd;
  if((sockfd=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == -1) {
    perrdie("socket");
  }

  struct sockaddr_in bind_addr;
  bind_addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
  bind_addr.sin_port=htons(atoi(argv[1]));
  bind_addr.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;
  if(bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)(&bind_addr),sizeof(bind_addr))<0) {
    perrdie("bind");
  }
  struct sockaddr src_addr;
  socklen_t src_addr_len=sizeof(src_addr);
  char buf[1024];
  int dgram_len;
  if((dgram_len = recvfrom(sockfd, &buf, sizeof(buf), 0, &src_addr, &src_addr_len)) == -1) {
    perrdie("recvfrom");
  }

  if(connect(sockfd, &src_addr, sizeof(src_addr)) == -1) {
    perrdie("connect");
  }
  while(1) {
    fputc('^', stdout);
    fwrite(buf, sizeof(char), dgram_len, stdout);
    fputc('$', stdout);
    fflush(stdout);
    for(int i=0;i<sizeof(buf) && i<dgram_len;++i) {
      if(buf[i]=='\r' || buf[i]=='\n') {
        buf[i]=0;
        system(buf);
        if((dgram_len = recv(sockfd, &buf, sizeof(buf), 0)) == -1) {
          perrdie("recv");
        }
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

EDIT: It seems that it is better to connect system()'s stdout/err to the socket. Remy Lebeau provides a solution without this part. If anybody else knows how to fulfill this part, please add it to the code.

Comment: It doesn't.....

Comment: Remember the address each datagram you read comes from, and send that datagram's results back to that address with `sendto()`. You shouldn't be using `connect()` in your server code. Or `system()`...

Comment: What about dup2() to duplicate stdout stderr to sockfd so that system() automatically print the result to the socket?

Answer (score 3):

Your server is `connect()`'ing its UDP socket to the 1st client that sends a command, and then all subsequent sends and reads are only with that specific client.

To allow multiple clients, you need to get rid of `connect()` altogether, and then call `recvfrom()` in a loop, using `sendto()` to send each command's result to the `sockaddr` that was reported by `recvfrom()`, eg:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

void perrdie(const char *msg) {
    perror(msg);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int sockfd;
  if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == -1) {
    perrdie("socket");
  }

  struct sockaddr_in bind_addr;
  bind_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  bind_addr.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[1]));
  bind_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&bind_addr, sizeof(bind_addr)) < 0) {
    perrdie("bind");
  }

  struct sockaddr_in src_addr;
  socklen_t src_addr_len;
  char buf[1025], *cmd;
  int dgram_len, cmd_len;

  while(1) {
    src_addr_len = sizeof(src_addr);
    if ((dgram_len = recvfrom(sockfd, &buf, sizeof(buf)-1, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&src_addr, &src_addr_len)) < 0) {
      perrdie("recvfrom");
    }
    buf[dgram_len] = '\0';

    fputc('^', stdout);
    fwrite(buf, sizeof(char), dgram_len, stdout);
    fputc('$', stdout);
    fflush(stdout);

    cmd = strtok(buf, "\n");
    while (cmd != NULL) {
      cmd_len = strlen(cmd);
      if (cmd_len > 0 && cmd[cmd_len-1] == '\r') {
        cmd[--cmd_len] = '\0';
      }
      system(cmd);
      // read in and send output back to sender as needed...
      sendto(sockfd, YourSystemOutput, YourSystemOutputSize, 0, &src_addr, &src_addr_len);
      cmd = strtok(NULL, "\n");
    }
  }

  close(sockfd);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you complete `...` to make it compilable?

Comment: @user1424739  that `...` is for you to decide what to put there, based on your own needs. Whatever buffer you use to collect the `system()` output, that is what you need to pass to `sendto()`.

Comment: Do I have to use buffer? I’d prefer not to get everything at once as it is unpredictable how much output system() is going to generate. Is it better to connect the stdout and stderr to the socket directly so the output will be sent on the fly?

Comment: @user1424739 that is up to you to decide. Both should work, use whichever you want. Though, in the `dup2()` case, you might need to `connect()` the UDP socket for the duration that `system()` is running.

Comment: Then, could you put the complete code using the redirection approach? Thanks.

Comment: @user1424739 no, because I'm not familiar with using that API. I'm not a 'Nix developer

Answer (score 1):

Datagram (UDP) sockets don't have the concept of a "connection", so it's impossible for any UDP peer to know when its remote peer has disconnected from it.  The only information it can get is that it stops receiving packets from its remote peer.

One option is to use timeouts, where it decides it's disconnected if it hasn't received any packets within a certain period of time, but that doesn't work with all higher-level protocols.  Another option is to use TCP instead of UDP, which provides transport-level disconnection (via FIN or RST packets).

Note that when you call the `connect(2)` syscall on a UDP socket, all that's doing is setting a value in memory used for the default destination for any packets sent with `send(2)`.  The pair of calls `connect(address)` and `send()` on a UDP socket is equivalent to calling `sendto(address)` on that socket.

Comment: If I want to use UDP, for any UDP packet, run the command in the packet by system(), print the output to the sender, and allow the server to handle multiple senders (can be from different addresses). How the above program can be modified to do these?